# How to use MySql.Data.dll in Android Project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am new in Android Application,
In my android application with C# base, i want to use MySqlConnection.
But when i add reference of MySql.Data.dll it gives me exception in VS 2010 and unable run my application.

Exception

> *Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Configuration.Install,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'System.Configuration.Install.dll'    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute()*

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use compiled desktop .Net libraries with Xamarin projects unless it is a PCL (Portable Class Library).

Your best bet is to download the source for MySQL.Data [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html#downloads).

Then make an Android Library project, and link-in all the C# files. It should be fairly straightforward, but you might run into a compiler error or two. Most of the work will be removing things that don't exist in Xamarin's subset of .Net.

Comment: I have already downloaded it and can you explain me how to add portable Class library

Comment: Is there a PCL version of MySQL.Data.dll? If so you should just be able to reference it directly. If you want to build a PCL version of it, just choose File->New Project->Portable Library in Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio, and link-in the files the same way you would on Android.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a device local solution you may want to try implementing a SQLLite solution vs trying to rig up a MySQL solution. SQLLite is well supported and natively supported by the os. Check out this link to get the item straight from Xamarin.
http://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net/
I've had a lot of luck using it.

Alternatively if your looking for an external MySQL connection then there is this link here.
http://www.mono-project.com/MySQL

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old question but I think that my answer would help people with the same problem.

So, I think exception occurs when you want to directly connect your android app with the database using MySql.Data.dll. Everyone who knows the security risks in this approach but still wants to do it in this way, should use MySql.Data.CF.dll instead of MySql.Data.dll. This will remove the exception (at least it was in my case).

However, I suggest using Web Service to enable interaction with database.

Hope my answer is helpful.